# Elasticsearch nested query and sorting

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

can somebody help me to understand what Elastic means by nested. In documentations https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_nested_sorting_examples is an example which does not show how the document object looks like. It look like I should imagine the mapping from the search query. Query looks like:

```
POST /_search
{
   "query": {
      "nested": {
         "path": "parent",
         "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {"range": {"parent.age": {"gte": 21}}},
                "filter": {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "parent.child",
                        "query": {"match": {"parent.child.name": "matt"}}
                    }
                }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort" : [
      {
         "parent.child.age" : {
            "mode" :  "min",
            "order" : "asc",
            "nested": {
               "path": "parent",
               "filter": {
                  "range": {"parent.age": {"gte": 21}}
               },
               "nested": {
                  "path": "parent.child",
                  "filter": {
                     "match": {"parent.child.name": "matt"}
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Can somebody write a document structure on which this query will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
{
    "parent": {
        "name": "Elasti Sorch",
        "age": 23,
        "child": [
           {
              "name": "Kibana Lion",
              "age": 12
           }, 
           {
              "name": "Matt",
              "age": 15
           }
        ] 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think child.age should be an array because of "mode": "min" has to be used there. Am I right? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_sort_mode_option

Comment: Yes. Totally missed that. Added it now.

Comment: Can you tell me please why `"must": {"range": {"parent.age": {"gte": 21}}},` part of the query is in nested sub-query if this condition is related to the parent?

Comment: Because age is child object of parent. If document would have been like {"parent_name":"Elastic Sorch", "parent_age":23 }, then it would not have been nested query.

Comment: I dont understand. Age should be the parent property. Also your edit is not correct. Only the age is an array. Child is not an array of objects but one nested object. I am sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: I think I am wrong. The child is an array of objects as you write.

Answer (score 1):

In Elastic nested means it's an array of objects. To store an array of objects into a field in elastic search you have to map the field to a nested while creating the index.

```
PUT parent
       {
       "mappings": {
        "doc":{
      "properties": {
        "name":{
          "type": "text"
        },
        "age":{
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "child":{
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "name":{
              "type":"text"
            },
            "age":{
              "type":"integer"
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and a sample nested document cab be inserted like this

```
POST parent/doc
{
  "name":"abc",
  "age":50,
  "child":[
    {
      "name":"son1",
      "age":25
    },
    {
      "name":"adughter1",
      "age":20
    }
    ]
}
```